# How to momentarily change the width of a layout object?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-videoview, android-framelayout

I have a layout XML, which contains a framelayout that has a videoview, and another framelayout that contains imageview. The framelayout with videoview wraps by content the width. I need to make it change the other framelayou with imageview as well. So when the videoview loads it should change the dimensions of the framelayout.

Is there any work around for this? I've tried `addOnLayoutChangeListener` but the change isn't immediate.

Comment: width of your framelayout with imageview is also wrap_content?

Comment: well the width of the videoview and imageview are different, I need to somehow make the width of imageview dependent on the width of videoview.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple . Try something like this.

1. Use one LinearLayout.
2. Add video view and ImageView init.
3. Video View with width 0dp and layout_weight 1 and ImageView width as wrap_content (or whatever).
4. Get Video Loaded event on Video View and simply make ImageView Visibility GONE.

   for example.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <VideoView android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: The problem is that the image should scale correspondingly to the width of the videoview

Comment: Not getting what you want to do exactly. please explain in more details and some pitures if possible.